# Stop sharing Macintosh HD and home folder with File Sharing?

Tags: macos, smb, file-sharing

I've seen quite a few questions posted here and on Reddit about this topic, but I haven't been able to find the solution I am looking for, or a straight up answer like "no you cant change that".

I have File Sharing with smb setup on my macbook pro to access files from my windows pc. What I want is to have my public shared folder that I can put folders and files in to grab on my pc whenever, and stop my "Bloumbs" home folder and entire Macintosh HD volume from being shared.

Is it possible to do that? If so, how?

[image: mac os file sharing]

[image: windows network file sharing]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Did you try sharing just the public folder by clicking on the `+` button below the Shared Folders list view?

Comment: @NimeshNeema Yes, when I add the public folder I want to share to the "Shared Folders", it does show up in my windows pc as a folder I can share from, but this does not remove my home folder or Macintosh HD from the shared folders on my pc. [Screenshot here](https://i.imgur.com/3G0BPPw.png)

Answer (score 3):

Turn off Volume shares (on by default)

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.smb.server VirtualAdminShares -bool NO
```

Turn off User shares (on by default)

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.smb.server VirtualHomeShares -bool NO
```

Then reboot your Mac.  I've tried a few combinations of using `launchctl unload -w` on the smbd service, but the shares stayed open until I rebooted :(

Answer (score 0):

There is a folder called Public in your home folder that is shared by default with read only privileges. You don't need to tick the file sharing option to share it.

Comment: That doesn't explain how to _unshare_ home and root. (EDITED)